# bandwidth on WAN link

Tags: dhcp

I would like to understand how a router is able to divide bandwidth among users who are using the same WAN link.

Comment: You really need to study QoS. It is a huge subject that includes what you want, but it fills entire books (far too huge to detail here), covering everything from classifying and marking packets, to treating them (queuing, shaping, policing). By default, the router is FIFO (First In, First Out), but you can modify that with QoS, and everyone has a different idea about how to use it (policies).

Answer (score 3):

Bandwidth sharing comes naturally with the granularity of packet switching. Data is packetized, packets are serialized through a network, queued on the other side and eventually forwarded elsewhere.

Picture a funnel with a tight neck. Now pour sand from multiple buckets of different colors into the funnel. The colors mix naturally through the neck. The funnel represents the queue, the neck the egress interface, and the neck size defines the egress bandwidth.

> is it parameters like TCP window size or something else? How does the ISR router identify this?

A router forwards packets on the network layer by destination IP address. It doesn't care whether they carry TCP, UDP or some other payload. Of course, it's TCP's responsibility (or the application's for UDP) to shape the traffic, so that it allows smooth forwarding, without causing congestion.

> If one user is using a 100 mbps link to download something from the internet, full bandwidth is allocated to that user, but for other users, the bandwidth gets equally divided.

If there's no concurrent demand, the ingress 100 Mbit/s stream is queued from the router's WAN port and immediately forwarded to the destination node. If multiple streams of 100 Mbit/s try to arrive on the WAN side, only 100 Mbit/s are accepted (not by your router but by the upstream port) and forwarded. The excess is dropped. TCP's congestion control detects that packet loss and adjusts its receive window to 'reduce pressure' from the WAN link. Since multiple TCP connection work in concert, the total bandwidth is (mostly) evenly distributed.

> Can we restrict the bandwidth for download traffic alone so utilisation can be prioritised?

Using QoS rules, you can shape and prioritize specific traffic, so that more sensitive applications (like VoIP) can continue to work reliably even when there's heavy competition over bandwidth = congestion.

All that is nothing specific to Cisco devices. Any decent business-grade router can do it.